# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_weasyprint'

Tags: python, flask, pip

i am getting error  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_weasyprint'`

when importing

`from flask_weasyprint import HTML, render_pdf`

when I set up an existing flask project. So I am trying to install flask_weasyprint using

`pip install Flask-WeasyPrint`

command but it gives below error. But i do not understand what is saying this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, seems like a bug.  Try `pip3 install Flask-WeasyPrint`

Comment: Hmmm. works for me.  Are you in a Python 3.x environment with pip3?

Comment: i am using `Python 3.8.1` with `pip 20.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you get this same [issue](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/1008)

Try:

```
py -m pip install wheel
```

In future [avoid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7041939) post screenshots of error.

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: wheel when ran above command after also getting same error when install `Flask-WeasyPrint`.

Comment: Try follow oficial [doc to install WeasyPrint in Windows](https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#windows) before install Flask extension.

Comment: The [cairocffi docs](https://cairocffi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#installing-cairo-on-windows) could help too.